# How to do an insertion sort on a list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, insertion-sort

I have a list of dictionaries with various keys, all of which are integers, and I need to write a function which uses insertion sort to sort them by the specific key.

```
def insertionsort(alldata, key):
    for i in alldata :
    temp = alldata[i]
    j = i
    while j > 0 and alldata[i['key']] < alldata[j - 1['key']]: # no idea how to put this
        alldata[j] = alldata[j-1]
    alldata[j] = temp
```

Comment: Are you doing this for a educational purposes? If not just use `sort` with `key` parameter.

Comment: @Igonato Yes for educational purposes!

Comment: You need to indent everything after the `for` loop. Also, you could get the keys by using `for (key_a, key_b) in (dict_a, dict_b):` and then do the comparison within the second for loop.

Comment: @movrev thanks so much! I understand the indentation part but unfortunately as I'm very new to python I have no idea how to complete the second part of your suggestion, could you please show me with some sample code?

Comment: I meant for you to use it like this: `for (key_i, key_j) in (alldata[i], alldata[j-1]):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i['key']` looks like mistake. You aren't using your `key` variable here.

Try `alldata[i][key] < alldata[j - 1][key]` as a condition

Also you need to change `j` in your while loop or it can ran forever

```
def insertionsort(alldata, key):
    for i in alldata :
        temp = alldata[i]
        j = i
        while j > 0 and alldata[i][key] < alldata[j - 1][key]:
           alldata[j] = alldata[j - 1]
           j -= 1
        alldata[j] = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Every thing after the for loop shuld be indented 1 more time (whatever number of spaces you use for indenting)
As for any other issues, I dont know.