# Using Insertion sort to sort list of dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

This sort is For Educational purposes. no build in sort is allowed.

**If you think my question and the answer helped, please vote me and the first answer people:
@J.F. Sebastian**

I have found this on SO --
"[How to do an insertion sort on a list of dictionaries in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801027/how-to-do-an-insertion-sort-on-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-python)"

but that answer does no seem right.

Using the answer code of the above question raises this error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict

Example :

```
lst = [{'a':20, 'b':30, 'c':25, 'd': 600},{'a':60, 'b':10, 'c':43, 'd': 20}]`
```

to sort using insertion sort,  for example sort `b`, we should get

```
[{'a':60, 'b':10, 'c':43, 'd': 20},{'a':20, 'b':30, 'c':25, 'd': 600}]
```

But my code gets

```
[{'b': 10, 'c': 25, 'a': 20, 'd': 600}, {'b': 30, 'c': 43, 'a': 60, 'd': 20}]
```

he replace the key and value in the list of dictionary

Here is my Code:

```
def insertionSort(allData, key):

    for i in range(len(allData)):
        temp = allData[i][key]
        j = i
        while j > 0 and temp < allData[j - 1][key]:
               allData[j][key] = allData[j - 1][key]
               j = j - 1
        allData[j][key] = temp
```

My homework sort result:

```
{'snow': 19.2, 'minT': -10.8, 'month': 12, 'maxT': 9.0, 'rain': 45.0, 'year': 2003, 'meanT': -0.1, 'yearmonth': 193801}
{'snow': 35.6, 'minT': -20.0, 'month': 1, 'maxT': 8.9, 'rain': 34.3, 'year': 1974, 'meanT': -5.9, 'yearmonth': 193802}
{'snow': 0.0, 'minT': 9.7, 'month': 8, 'maxT': 34.8, 'rain': 20.8, 'year': 2007, 'meanT': 22.4, 'yearmonth': 193803}`
```

After sorting the `yearmonth`, they replace the `yearmonth` from small to big, but not changing the dictionary.

Why does this happen, and how shoudl I change it?

==================================

**Answer:**

After some basic copy of 'J.F. Sebastian' code
I find that I can't directly using the code

```
sort(a,b)
```

output:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I should use
    sort(a,b=lambda x: x['thekey'])
then, JFS makes a new function to make it work.

I also find another way:
just change JFS code line 5:

**from**

```
    if key(L[j]) <= key(d):
```

***to***

```
    if L[j][key] <= d[key]:
```

THEN EVERYTHING WORKS!
Hope this can help other people too, and those using google and doing the same assignment as me.

Comment: I don't quite get the question. Is this about how to sort a list of dictionary comparing the values of a given key present in all dictionaries in that list?

Comment: what is the sort criteria for dictionaries? The builtin `sorted` returns the second result (if the dict were the same). Note: the keys *inside* dictionaries are unordered i.e., `{'a':1, 'b':2}` and `{'b':2, 'a':1}` are the same.

Comment: The question is I what to sort the list of dict by the key value in the dictionary

Comment: @ J.F.Sebastian - The point is not allowing using build in sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write an insertion sort procedure that works with integer lists. Then it is easy to modify it to accept a `key` parameter, to allow arbitrary comparisons:

```
def insertion_sort_impl(L, *, key):
    for i in range(1, len(L)): # loop-invariant: `L[:i]` is sorted
        d = L[i]
        for j in range(i - 1, -1, -1): 
            if key(L[j]) <= key(d): 
               break
            L[j + 1] = L[j]
        else: # `key(L[j]) > key(d)` for all `j`
            j -= 1
        L[j + 1] = d
```

Example:

```
lst = [{'a':20, 'b':30, 'c':25, 'd': 600},{'a':60, 'b':10, 'c':43, 'd': 20}]
insertion_sort_impl(lst, key=lambda x: x['d']) # sort by `d` key
print(lst)
```

#### Output

```
[{'a': 60, 'c': 43, 'b': 10, 'd': 20}, {'a': 20, 'c': 25, 'b': 30, 'd': 600}]
```

Note: ignore the order of keys inside dictionary. It may change from run to run, but the dictionary with the key `d` that has lesser value will always be on the left.

The name `key` for `insertion_sort_impl()` function is unrelated to dictionary key. It is a naming convention that is used by many builtin functions; `key` is used to get a value to be used for comparison:

```
>>> max([1, 2], key=lambda x: -x)
1
>>> min([1, -2], key=lambda x: x*x)
1
>>> sorted([-1, 0, 1], key=lambda x: x*x-x)
[0, 1, -1]
```

To understand, why the loop is started at `1`, you could read the general description of [Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

If the interface of `insertion_sort` function is fixed then you could define it in terms of `insertion_sort_impl`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def insertion_sort(L, key):
    return insertion_sort_impl(L, key=itemgetter(key))
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is,in sort(L, key), key is called from another function. what I will get is key='a'. For example, then the function is isort(abc, 'a') not isort(abc, key=lambda x: x['a']). Than it will raise "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable". When using insertion_sort(lst, key=lambda x: x['d']). everything works fine. So how to make sort(lst, 'key') works fine as well? I don't even understand why i range start from 1. Could you explain that? I am a noob :)

Comment: @MarquisRandell: read the line in my post that says "sort by `'d'` key. What do you think should be changed in that line to sort by `'a'` key? Note: `lambda x: x['d']` is similar to `operator.itemgetter('d')`

Comment: @MarquisRandell: I've added link to the general description of the algorithm to the answer

Comment: What I mean is when using sort(abc, 'd') will not work, but sort(abc, key=lambda x: x['d']) worked. But my key is control by not modify code teacher. which is the main function called  -->insertion_sort(lst, 'd') . then it comes "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: @MarquisRandell:  I've added an explanation about why key is named key in `insertion_sort_impl()` function.